# Populate Dropdown Box if 2 columns match with values from 3rd column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am using Data Validation lists in Excel for something based on a data dictionary from a database. Setup is as follow:

```
    Sheet1
    column A - DB Table Name (repeats for as many rows as there are associated values in column B)
    Column B - List of all values associated with the DB table name in column A
```

```
Example Sheet1
Column A  |  Column B
DB1       | ValueA1
DB1       | ValueA2
DB1       | ValueA3
DB2       | ValueB1
DB3       | ValueC1
DB3       | ValueC2
```

On Sheet 2 I have a dropdown Data Validation in cell D1 that is populated from a table. All of the options in the table are the DB names in ColumnA of Sheet1. Based on the DB selection from the cell D1 on Sheet2 I want B1 of sheet2 to be a dropdown list of all of the matching values from Sheet1 column B where Sheet2 cell D1 matches Sheet1 columnA.

Example: Person selects DB3 in Sheet2 Cell D1. Then cell B1 in Sheet2 becomes a dropdown containing the values [ValueC1, ValueC2]. Those are the column B values from Sheet1 that name-match Sheet2 D1 and Sheet1 column A.

Tried numerous things with Index and vlookup but I am not getting multiple results so the data validation won't take the formula as it only returns a single result.

I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1] In "`sheet 1`", Column C `C2:C4` create a "UniqueList of data A"  : enter DB1,DB2 and DB3

2] In "`sheet 2`" `D1` >> `Data Validation` >>

> > Allow : `List`
> >
> > Source : `=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4`
> >
> > Select `OK`

3] In "`sheet 2`" `B1` >> `Data Validation` >>

> > Allow : `List`
> >
> > Source : `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,MATCH($D1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,0),0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,$D1))`
> >
> > Select `OK`

[image]

Comment: Hi Bosco, thank you for that reply. Is that the best way to handle it if column A has 1200 Rows? If so I'll make a giant list but the sheet is pretty large

Comment: @DaveyLions, as per Contextures.com mentioned, "a data validation list can show up to show 32,767 items from a list on the worksheet".

Comment: Awesome, I will try this when I return to the office and update to mark as solved. Thank you